# Populate cell with the current date when spreadsheet is opened VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How can I insert today's date in the cell when spreadsheet opens, so that if someone wants to change it then they can do it by changing it right within the cell.

I have tried the following, but without much luck

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim temp As String

    If Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = "" Then
        Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = Date
    End If
End Sub
```

The cell is a named range "_invoiceDate" and worksheet is "Home"

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: can you please, rephrase your question, because I really can't understand what you need..

Comment: Do you mean "when the workbook opens"?

Comment: Sorry, Basically what I need is have a current date available in the cell range "_invoiceDate" when I open my spreadsheet

Comment: maybe you need to use `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` event instead `Worksheet_Change`?

Comment: @simoco, I have tried this, but it does not change the picture at all

Comment: btw, remove `Home.`, just use `Range("_invoiceDate").Value` and put your code in `Sheet(Home)` module and as simpLe MAn said, try to remove `If Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = "" Then` and `End If`

Comment: @simoco; that is true, `Home` means nothing there.  Since you are already within the code module of sheet "Home", you can write it as simoco's comment.  In fact, are you writing this code in sheet "home" code module?

Comment: Also, did you try `Worksheet_Activate()` instead of `Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)` as simoco said?

Comment: @simoco, I have removed everything as you've suggested, here is my code, but it still wont work for me for some reason. Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Range("_invoiceDate").Value = Date
End Sub

Comment: can you clarify please, how it doesn't work? if sheet you've activated has named range `_invoiceDate`, then it's value should be changed to current date

Comment: Home!$C$7 is _invoiceDate but nothing is happening even when I close and reopen

Comment: add line `MsgBox ActiveSheet.Name` in the `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` event. What message do you get when active sheet?

Comment: Ok, it worked only when I am switching between workbooks but not when I Open the spreadsheet for the first time

Comment: `when I am switching between workbooks` - actually between _worksheets_. As I understood you need to go with @Mike's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the code to run when you open the workbook, you will need to place the code in the Workbook sheet like this.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    dim Home as Worksheet
    set Home = Worksheets("Home")
    Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = Format(Now(),"mm/dd/yyyy")  
End Sub
```

I believe this is what you are looking for.

I tested this for switching between worksheets and it works fine.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim Home As Worksheet
Set Home = Worksheets("Home")
Home.Range("_invoiceDate").Value = Format(Now(), "mm/dd/yyyy")

End Sub
```

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thank Mike, the second version works when you are switching between the worksheets, but when I've used the fist version of your code nothing happens, any ideas?

Comment: The first version only works when you first open the workbook.  I'll use this area to initialize values, present opportunities to the user for a userform, etc.  When you first open the vba editor, it is the last sheet in the list and is called ThisWorkbook.  Glad the code worked for you!

Comment: I have got to admit, it was my mistake since I was not placing your code correctly, I have found my mistake and everything works just fine now. Thanks a lot